# How to call a function several times when the function has sub dependant variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, dependencies, row

**THE SCENARIO**

- Each gridview has several fields whose values are determined using rowindex.
- Values are submitted using row command by executing a function.
- The function is **used several times** on a page so has been moved to a private sub to prevent code duplication.

**THE PROBLEM**

- The function has dependant variables that are bound to the row and so cannot be declared in the private sub.

**THE QUESTION**

- How to call a function several times *(without duplicating unnecessary code)* when the function has sub dependant variables?

**THE CODE (VB.NET)**

```
Protected Sub gv_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Rows(rowIndex)

    Dim TxBx As Integer = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtbox"), TextBox).Text

    If (e.CommandName = "EditRow") Then
        Me.MyFunction()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyFunction()
    'How can this function read row dependant variables? i.e TxBx's value
End Sub
```

**NOTES**

I am aware that the function should simply be coded within the row command sub however the scope of this question is **how to not duplicate functions**?

Comment: You could pass the relevant variables as parameters into the function.

Comment: Of course seems obvious doesnt it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved quite simply by passing the variables into the function as parameters.

**ASP.NET**

```
Protected Sub gv_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Rows(rowIndex)

    Dim TxBx As Integer = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtbox"), TextBox).Text

    If (e.CommandName = "EditRow") Then
        Me.MyFunction(TxBx)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyFunction(TxBx As Integer)

End Sub
```